# Get specific values of nested object within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I make an AJAX request and I receive this (looking at the Network tab)

```
[
    {
        "request": "Amount of rainfall by day",
        "days": [
            {
                "day": 1,
                "amount": 50
            }, {
                "day": 2,
                "amount": 10
            }, {
                "day": 3,
                "amount": 10
            }, {
                "day": 4,
                "amount": 150
            }, {
                "day": 5,
                "amount": 130
            }, {
                "day": 6,
                "amount": 45
            }, {
                "day": 7,
                "amount": 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to create an array with the values of 'amount'.

```
[50,10,10,150,130,45,10]
```

(the order is important; I will show these values in a chart with chronological order)

I tried lodash.values as well as `for..in` but the mix between nested arrays and nested objects is rather confusing.

I would like an elegant solution.

Question 1: Should I use a Json method to remove the outside root level array ? Any way to get rid of it?

Question 2: Which data structure should I use in order to keep the relation between days and amounts? (my charting library, [Chart.js](http://alpha.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart) receives a simple array of single values.

Comment: What is a "JSON method"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array from the requested values:

```js
var data = [{"request":"Amount of rainfall by day","days":[{"day":1,"amount":50},{"day":2,"amount":10},{"day":3,"amount":10},{"day":4,"amount":150},{"day":5,"amount":130},{"day":6,"amount":45},{"day":7,"amount":10}]}];

var result = data[0].days.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.amount;
});

console.log(result);
```

---

**Question 1**

You can tranverse it easily by using `data[0]`, and after you'll map / reduce, you'll get a new data structure.

---

**Question 2**

You can use a simple object, with two related arrays by using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var data = [{"request":"Amount of rainfall by day","days":[{"day":1,"amount":50},{"day":2,"amount":10},{"day":3,"amount":10},{"day":4,"amount":150},{"day":5,"amount":130},{"day":6,"amount":45},{"day":7,"amount":10}]}];

var result = data[0].days.reduce(function(r, o) {
  r.days.push(o.day);
  r.amounts.push(o.amount);
  
  return r;
}, { days: [], amounts: [] });

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: wait a sec.. `data[0].days` is an array with *1* element.. I thought .map runs on an array of multiple elements.. what am I missing?

Comment: `data[0]` returns the array of `days`, which has multiple elements that we can map.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Lodash to answer your question

```
var response = [
    {
        "request": "Amount of rainfall by day",
        "days": [
            {
                "day": 1,
                "amount": 50
            }, {
                "day": 2,
                "amount": 10
            }, {
                "day": 3,
                "amount": 10
            }, {
                "day": 4,
                "amount": 150
            }, {
                "day": 5,
                "amount": 130
            }, {
                "day": 6,
                "amount": 45
            }, {
                "day": 7,
                "amount": 10
            }
        ]
    }
]; 
// using _.map function 
_.map(response[0].days, 'amount');
```

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#map)

Comment: var days = _.map(response[0].days, 'day');                                                  var amounts = _.map(response[0].days, 'amount');                                past these to arrays to ur chart.                                                               Eg:-                                                                                                           var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: days,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Amount',
            data: amounts
        }]
    },
});

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
var reply = [
    {
        "request": "Amount of rainfall by day",
        "days": [
            {
                "day": 1,
                "amount": 50
            }, {
                "day": 2,
                "amount": 10
            }, {
                "day": 3,
                "amount": 10
            }, {
                "day": 4,
                "amount": 150
            }, {
                "day": 5,
                "amount": 130
            }, {
                "day": 6,
                "amount": 45
            }, {
                "day": 7,
                "amount": 10
            }
        ]
    }
];

var amounts = reply[0].days.map((i) => { return i.amount });
console.log(amounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the `day` property value does not follow the order of the elements in the response object, you may need to use that value as index in your final array. Here is an ES6 solution:

```js
var response = [
    {
        "request": "Amount of rainfall by day",
        "days": [
            {
                "day": 1,
                "amount": 50
            }, {
                "day": 2,
                "amount": 10
            }, {
                "day": 3,
                "amount": 10
            }, {
                "day": 4,
                "amount": 150
            }, {
                "day": 5,
                "amount": 130
            }, {
                "day": 6,
                "amount": 45
            }, {
                "day": 7,
                "amount": 10
            }
        ]
    }
];

var arr = response[0].days.reduce( (arr, o) => (arr[o.day-1] = o.amount, arr), []);

console.log(arr);
```

So this would even work if the value for day 4 were missing. The value at the corresponding index in the output array (index 3) would have `undefined` in that case.